# What is a descriptive name for a web service that responds with plain text?

Tags: web, service, text

I'm looking for the proper name for a web service that responds with text as opposed to XML. As an example this "cardServer" service will return 5 cards for a poker hand.

```
http://hostname:8080/cardServer/deal/Game=Poker&Qty=5
```

The result could look like this:

```
Card1=Ad
Card2=Kc
Card3=Ts
Card4=5d
Card5=3d
```

The real world example is not as trivial, but the concept is the same. Parameters if any are passed as POST variables.

We currently parse the response into a string list and use the values. The process works just fine. 
What I'm wondering if this service method has a name that has easier tools to deal with the responses and therefore did we reinvent the wheel? For the record the service was provided and maintained by a customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API.  Or maybe a an event driven SOA web service. At least that's what I'd call it.

Comment: When in doubt "web API" is usually safe :)

Comment: I think my problem is that this is considered a Servlet and not a Web Service by some of the definitions I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Text Webservice?

Straight-up WebService is pretty generic but to overcome the standard XML WebService assumption you'll probably just need to describe it like it is.